# Can't centre title text in a navigation bar

Tags: ios

I can't get the title text displaying in the navigation bar to be centered. In general, but also specifically if I add a left bar button item then the title text shifts to the right.

I have a segmented control and depending upon which segment the user chooses the title text can change, and with one of the segments a left bar button will appear, then disappear if the user chooses another segment. The code to add the title is:

```
- (void) setHeader
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
switch (self.filterType)
{
    case filterx:
        label.text = @"the title":
        break;
    // etc.
}

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;  
}
```

I've tried experimenting setting self.navigationItem.titleView.center explicitly, or to the centre of the view, or to the centre of the navigation bar but none of that makes any difference.

Comment: Let's see a screen shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen because there may be some other view like leftBarButton, backButton or rightBarButton which causing this issue. Actually you are creating label of width 320.0f which is the complete width of `navigation bar`. You need to deduct the size of other views of navigation bar from you label width and it will work for you.

Comment: Can you explain how to get the width the Back button?